# Get-ChildItem -Directory not working name

Tags: .net, powershell, powershell-3.0

In PowerShell 3.0 I'm trying to right a script to give me a certain directory from an input parameter. The input parameter can be either relative or full path. I am having issues just passing it into the New-Object with a System.IO.DirectoryInfo because the Current working directory for PowerShell doesn't appear to match my current working directory for relative paths. So I tried the Get-ChildItem. If I run the command `Get-ChildItem -Directory` it will list out all the directories. In the results I see a folder named Queries. If I run `Get-ChildItem -Directory "Queries"`. It returns nothing.

So two questions.

1. Why does it do this and how do I get around it?
2. What is the best way to get a DirectoryInfo object in PowerShell given that the path can be relative or rooted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be better off using `Resolve-Path` instead. As for getting the Queries folder from GCI you probably want something along the lines of `GCI .\ -Directory -Filter "Queries"`

Comment: Resolve-Path Works perfectly. Thank you. I've long abandoned the GCI :(.

Comment: Resolve-Path actually returns a PathInfo object. Not a DirectoryInfo. Get-Item will return a DirectoryInfo. Either or should work for what I need though.

Answer (score 0):

Flip the tokens? `Gci queries -directory`

Answer (score 0):

Because there is not a parameter for `Get-ChildItem` named `-Directory` .. The parameter you are looking for is `-path`

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849800.aspx

`Get-ChildItem -Path Queries` will work

To get a `System.Io.DirectoryInfo` object just assign it to a variable

`$queries = Get-ChildItem -Path Queries`

Comment: In powershell 3.0 there is a parameter named -Directory. It filters to be directories only. Also that returns the items inside the folder Queries. Not the directory itself

Comment: @dko Weird that it is no where to be found in the documentation... when you type `get-childitem -d` `tab` the directory parameter auto-completes? Just do a `Get-ChildItem -Path Queries | ? {$_.PSISCONTAINER}` to get only directories

Comment: dko is right. The `-Directory` parameter in PowerShell version 3.0 and later returns only directories, instead of directories and files.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found an answer to this. If I use `Get-Item "Queries"` vs `Get-ChildItem` it should give me everything that is needed. Thank you for your help.